# All of you, just let me be

Tags: riddle, wordplay

I was there at the beginning of the beginning.
I will turn my life around.
And be there at the end of the end.

But for now just let me be.

Who am I?

Comment: As I've stated before. I'm new at asking questions here Downvoting, without explaining why, won't make me improve the quality of my questions. It will most probably (if it happens repeatedly) discourage me from posting any other questions in the future.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was there at the beginning of the beginning.

> There is 'b' at the beginning of the beginning.

I will turn my life around.
And be there at the end of the end.

> When we rotate 'b' then it becomes 'd' and that's what we find at the end of the word 'end'.

But for now just let me be.

> It is B.

Comment: Beat me by seconds!

Comment: Oh come on....I knew I was making it easy, but not that easy. Good job.